# Makefile that covers interfaces (.h files)

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, polymorphism

I am implementing Collection hierarchy and in this project I need some abstract classes that have no function to implement so it seems redundant to  create .cpp files for these classes. 
I have a Makefile that works fine with .cpp files, but in this case some problems occured.

> The files that includes abstract classes (every function is abstract):
>
> ```
>  -collection.h
>  -set.h
>  -list.h
>  -queue.h
> ```
>
> These are files includes concrete functions:
>
> ```
>  -hashSet.h
>  -hashSet.cpp
>  -arrayList.h
>  -arrayList.cpp
>  -linkedList.h
>  -linkedList.cpp
>  -iterator.h
>  -iterator.cpp
> ```

and my Makefile is below

```
obj = main.o collection.o set.o list.o queue.o hashSet.o arrayList.o iterator.o

output : $(obj)
    g++ -g -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11 -ansi -pedantic -Wall $(obj) -o output

main.o : main.cpp
    g++  -g -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11 -c main.cpp

%.o : %.cpp %.h
    g++  -g -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11 -c $<

clean :
    rm *.o output
```

Current error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'collection.o', needed by 'output'.  Stop.
```

Can you help me to redesign the Makefile?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but this looks like you’re trying to write Java code in C++. That rarely ends well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know, the purpose of a header file in C++ is to be `#include`-ed, by
the preprocessor when it preprocesses a `.cpp` file, so that it simply *becomes a part*
of the source code that is consumed by the compiler when that `.cpp` file is compiled.

So a header file `header.h` is never individually compiled, and no corresponding object file `header.o`
is ever produced. `header.h` is `#include`-ed in, say, `source.cpp`; `source.cpp` is compiled,
including the contents of `header.h`, and the object file produced is `source.o`.

`source.o` obviously depends on `source.cpp`: whenever `source.cpp` is changed, you
need to recompile it to produce a new `source.o`. But because `source.cpp` includes `header.h`,
it is equally true that `source.o` depends on `header.h`: so whenever `header.h` is changed,
you again need to recompile `source.cpp` to produce a new `source.o`.

These are the questions you need to answer in a makefile:

- What are the files on which `source.o` depends?
- What needs to be done when `source.o` is not up-to-date (i.e. does not exist or is older than some
  file(s) that it depends on).

In Make-speak, the files that *X* depends on are called *the prerequisites* of *X*,
and the actions that must be executed to make *X* up-to-date are *the recipe* for *X*.

So your makefile needs to say that:

- `source.o` depends on `source.cpp`
- `source.o` depends on `header.h`
- When `source.o` is not up-to-date, `source.cpp` must be compiled to produce `source.o`

And that's all, as far as `header.h` is concerned.

Here's a concrete illustration something like your class-hierarchy project
with its header-only abstract base class:-

**shape.h**

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

struct shape {
    virtual ~shape() = default;
    virtual double area() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

**rectangle.h**

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

#include <shape.h>

struct rectangle : shape {
    rectangle(double length, double width);
    ~rectangle() override = default;
    double area() const override;
private:
    double _length;
    double _width;
};

#endif
```

**triangle.h**

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

#include <shape.h>

struct triangle : shape {
    triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3);
    ~triangle() override = default;
    double area() const override;
private:
    double _side1;
    double _side2;
    double _side3;
};

#endif
```

**rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "rectangle.h"

rectangle::rectangle(double length, double width)
: _length(length),_width(width){}

double rectangle::area() const {
    return _length * _width;
}
```

**triangle.cpp**

```
#include "triangle.h"
#include <cmath>

triangle::triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
: _side1(side1),_side2(side2),_side3(side3){}

double triangle::area() const {
    double halfperim = (_side1 + _side2 + _side3) / 2;
    double area2ed = halfperim *
        (halfperim - _side1) * (halfperim - _side2) * (halfperim - _side3);
    return std::sqrt(area2ed);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <shape.h>
#include <triangle.h>
#include <rectangle.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<shape> s{new rectangle{2,3}};
    std::cout << "Rectangular shape's area is " << s->area() << std::endl;
    s.reset(new triangle{3,4,5});
    std::cout << "Triangular shape's area is " << s->area() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile (1)**

```
# Builds program `prog`

.PHONY: clean   # `clean` is a phony target, not a real file

prog: main.o rectangle.o triangle.o     # Prerequisites of `prog`

prog:   # This is how to make `prog` up-to-date
    g++ -o $@ $^    # Link all the prerequisites (`$^`), output the target (`$@`)

main.o: main.cpp shape.h rectangle.h triangle.h     # Prerequisites of `main.o`
rectangle.o: rectangle.cpp rectangle.h shape.h      # Prerequisites of `rectangle.o`
triangle.o: triangle.cpp triangle.h shape.h         # Prerequisites of `triangle.o`

%.o:    # This is how to make any `*.o` file up-to-date
    g++ -c -o $@ $<     # Compile the first prerequisite (`$<`), output the target

clean:
    rm -f prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o
```

`Makefile` is written in an unrealistic style to minimise distractions
and emphasise the distinction between specifying the prerequisites of a target
and specifying the actions that make it up-to-date. But it's correct and runs
first time like:

```
$ make
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`main.cpp`), output the target
g++ -c -o rectangle.o rectangle.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`rectangle.cpp`), output the target
g++ -c -o triangle.o triangle.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`triangle.cpp`), output the target
g++ -o prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o    # Link all the prerequisites (`main.o rectangle.o triangle.o`), output the target (`prog`)
```

After which `prog` runs like:

```
$ ./prog
Rectangular shape's area is 6
Triangular shape's area is 6
```

If you modify `triangle.cpp` then `triangle.o` and `prog` will become out-of-date.
We can fake a modification with the `touch` shell command:

```
$ touch triangle.cpp
$ make
g++ -c -o triangle.o triangle.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`triangle.cpp`), output the target
g++ -o prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o    # Link all the prerequisites (`main.o rectangle.o triangle.o`), output the target (`prog`)
```

If you modify `rectangle.h` then `rectangle.o`, `main.o` and `prog` will become out-of-date:

```
$ touch rectangle.h
$ make
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`main.cpp`), output the target
g++ -c -o rectangle.o rectangle.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`rectangle.cpp`), output the target
g++ -o prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o    # Link all the prerequisites (`main.o rectangle.o triangle.o`), output the target (`prog`)
```

And if you modify `shape.h` (the abstract base class) then all the object files, plus `prog`, will become out of date:

```
$ touch shape.h
$ make
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`main.cpp`), output the target
g++ -c -o rectangle.o rectangle.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`rectangle.cpp`), output the target
g++ -c -o triangle.o triangle.cpp     # Compile the first prerequisite (`triangle.cpp`), output the target
g++ -o prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o    # Link all the prerequisites (`main.o rectangle.o triangle.o`), output the target (`prog`)
```

If `Makefile` were written in a slightly more professional style it would look like:

**Makefile (2)**

```
SRCS := main.cpp rectangle.cpp triangle.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

main.o: rectangle.h triangle.h shape.h
rectangle.o: rectangle.h shape.h
triangle.o: triangle.h shape.h

clean:
    $(RM) prog $(OBJS)
```

You can investigate its features in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)<sup>1</sup>
Notice in particular two differences from `Makefile` (1):-

**1**) It is usual to *combine* specifying prerequisites for a target with specifying its
recipe. So:

```
prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

is just a shorter way of writing:

```
prog: $(OBJS)

prog:
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

or indeed:

```
prog: main.o
prog: rectangle.o
prog: triangle.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

`make` combines all of the prerequisites of `prog` into one list and executes the recipe
if the target is out-of-date with respect to any of them.

**2**) The recipe for making the `*.o` files has disappeared, but the makefile
still works!

```
$ make clean
rm -f prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o
$ make
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++    -c -o rectangle.o rectangle.cpp
g++    -c -o triangle.o triangle.cpp
g++ -o prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o
```

That's because `make` has a repertoire of [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html),
and one of those built-in rules is a default recipe for making `file.o` from `file.cpp`. The default recipe is:

```
%.o: %.cpp:
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $@ $<
```

So we don't need to tell `make` that, e.g. `rectangle.o` depends on `rectangle.cpp`
or tell it what to do if that dependency makes `rectangle.o` out-of-date. If it
needs `rectangle.o` to be up-to-date and finds `rectangle.cpp`, then the built-in
rule tells it to compile `rectangle.cpp` and output `rectangle.o`.

But `make` has no built-in rule telling it that `rectangle.o` depends on `rectangle.h`
or that `main.o` depends on `shape.h` or on `triangle.h`. There is an infinite variety
of such possible dependencies, because there is no systematic relationship at all
between the name of an object file and the names of the header files that might be
included when compiling a source file to produce that object file.

Therefore the dependencies of object files upon *header* files *do* have to be
spelled out in the makefile:

```
main.o: rectangle.h triangle.h shape.h
rectangle.o: rectangle.h shape.h
triangle.o: triangle.h shape.h
```

Now spelling out the header-file dependencies "by hand" like this is practical
when our project is absurdly simple, like `prog`. But in real-life projects
it is not practical. There may be hundreds of source files and hundreds of
header files and one source file may recursively include headers from
within headers from within headers... Generally it is unrealistic for us to
unravel these recursions when we need to write a makefile.

However, it is not unrealistic for *the compiler* (or strictly, the preprocessor)
to unravel them: it has to do exactly that when it preprocesses a source file.

So the normal way of dealing with header-file dependencies, when working
with GNU Make and GCC, exploits a feature of the GCC preprocessor that exists
*for the purpose of solving this problem*. Using this feature to rewrite `Makefile`
again, in a still more professional style, it would be:

**Makefile (3)**

```
SRCS := main.cpp rectangle.cpp triangle.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) prog $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

-include $(DEPS)
```

You see here that we've brought back a recipe for making `file.o` from
`file.cpp`, in the form of a [*pattern-rule*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html)
Our pattern-rule:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -o $@ $<
```

calls the C++ compiler (`$(CXX))` to compile `file.cpp` and output `file.o`, and
passes it the preprocessor 
option [`-MMD`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

This option tells the preprocessor to write an additional outputfile, called `file.d` if the
object file is `file.o`, and `file.d` will be a *makefile* that expresses all the
prerequisites of `file.o` that the preprocessor has discovered by parsing `file.cpp` (excluding system header files).

Let's have a look:

```
$ make clean
rm -f prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o main.d rectangle.d triangle.d
$ make
g++ -c -MMD -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -MMD -o rectangle.o rectangle.cpp
g++ -c -MMD -o triangle.o triangle.cpp
g++ -o prog main.o rectangle.o triangle.o

$ cat main.d
main.o: main.cpp shape.h triangle.h rectangle.h

$ cat rectangle.d
rectangle.o: rectangle.cpp rectangle.h shape.h

$ cat triangle.d
triangle.o: triangle.cpp triangle.h shape.h
```

As you see, `file.d` is a mini-makefile that specfies the prerequisites
of `file.o`.

```
DEPS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)
```

makes `$(DEPS)` into the list `main.d rectangle.d triangle.d`. And:

```
-include $(DEPS)
```

includes all of those mini-makefiles in `Makefile` (3). So `Makefile` (3)
is equivalent to:

**Makefile (4)**

```
SRCS := main.cpp rectangle.cpp triangle.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) prog $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

main.o: main.cpp shape.h triangle.h rectangle.h

rectangle.o: rectangle.cpp rectangle.h shape.h

triangle.o: triangle.cpp triangle.h shape.h
```

This technique of getting the preprocessor to figure out the header file
dependencies that are too complicated to figure out by brain-power is
usually called *auto-dependency generation*, and this is the professional
way of dealing with the problem you are asking about.

There's just one snag with it you may have noticed already. Those `.d` files
are created by the processor when `make` runs the recipe for pattern `%.o: %.cpp`.
And they have to be `include`-ed in `Makefile`. But since they won't ever exist until
you've run `make` for the first time, trying to `include` them is bound to fail
when you *do* run `make` for the first time. A chicken-and-egg problem.

The get-out from that problem is just to *ignore* the failure of `include $(DEPS)`
if the `$(DEPS)` do not yet exist, and that's why we write:

```
-include $(DEPS)
```

instead of just:

```
include $(DEPS)
```

Prefixing `-` to a command in a makefile tells `make` to ignore failure.

You can take a deeper dive into auto-dependency generation by reading [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

---

[1]

- [6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)
- [6.3.1 Substitution References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html)
- [4.6 Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)
- [10.3 Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

`collection`, `set`, `list` and `queue` are headers only : they won't generate any object code for themselves (via g++ for instance), only targets that link against them will.

You can, for instance, write `collection.cpp` that just includes `collection.h`.

Then again, is it even relevant to have such an approach? Being "pure virtual classes", do they really need an implementation file for themselves? Isn't include their definition in the targets enough?

Either remove the `.o`s in the dependency list or write the "empty" implementation files so that it can generate object code for them.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your help. But I still have a problem, when I change a file make file seems recompile the program then I am receive the same output with prev one, after that I run make clean, make, ./output command and output is change. What do you think about it ?